# can't find the lib for the org.apache.hadoop.conf in hadoop 2.4.0

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I have been working on the hadoop-2.4.0, in order to run java based hadoop example, I have put the needed lib on the CLASSPATH

```
export HADOOP_HOME= /root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0    
CLASSPATH=/root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0/conf
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/*:$HADOOP_HOME/lib/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../hadoop-mapreduce/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../hadoop-yarn/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../hadoop-yarn/lib/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../hadoop-hdfs/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../hadoop-hdfs/lib/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../common/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../common/lib/*
CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:$HADOOP_HOME/../tools/lib/*
```

I have added all the needed HADOOP libraries from the HADOOP_HOME into the CLASSPATH.

However, when I tried to run the example
 javac -cp $CLASSPATH HelloWorld.java

It reminds me a error

```
HelloWorld.java:4: error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;                                 ^
1 error
```

I don't know where to find the lib for the org.apache.hadoop.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

Print your CLASSPATH

> echo $CLASSPATH

There is space in your 'export'

> export HADOOP_HOME="space"/root/hadoop-binaries/hadoop-2.4.0

Hope that helps